# Resize PDF when loading with FPDI into TCPDF

Tags: php, tcpdf, fpdi

I use FPDI to load certain pages out of a PDF into TCPDF and output a new PDF file. Some of the PDF files I am loading have pages that are slightly bigger than 8.5x11. Is there any way I could resize them down somewhere during this process?

Answer (score 0):

the only Solution i know is to specifiv the width&height in the "useTemplate" method,
see fpdi documention on setting width/height.
i dont know about any function to automatically resize the page.

hope that helped!